# Is there a way to search through specific keys within an object and then log the results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to work out how to search through an object to check if there is a match with the search value. From there I want to list which objects had a match.

For this example I want to search through `name1` and `name2` and see if either of them have an `options` value of `C`. If there is a match then list which objects matched the search. If the search value was for `A` it would then show up only `name1`.

I've tried setting up the `myObject` with data but I'm not sure how to loop through the object, check specific values of the `options` key to compare them with the search.

```js
let myObject = {
  name1: {
    title: 'Mr',
    options: ['A', 'B', 'C'],

  },

  name2: {
    title: 'Mrs',
    options: ['C', 'D', 'E'],

  }
};


function myFunction() {

  var optionSearch = 'C';

  console.log(optionSearch);
  for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    if (myObject[i].options == optionSearch)
      console.log(myObject[i] + ' is equal to optionSearch');
    else {
      console.log('No match');
    }
  }
}

myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myObject = {
  name1: {
    title: 'Mr', 
    options: ['A', 'B', 'C'], 

  },
  name2: {
    title: 'Mrs', 
    options: ['C', 'D', 'E'], 

  }
};

function myFunction(optionSearch) {
  console.log(optionSearch);
  for(var i in myObject) {
    if (myObject[i].options.indexOf(optionSearch) >= 0)
      console.log(i + ' is equal to optionSearch');
    else {
      console.log('No match');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Applying this approach worked for me. Thanks very much Samir!

Answer (score 1):

Objects don't have a default `length` property. So, you can't use `for` loop with numerical indexes. You can instead use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop through the object like this:

```js
let myObject = {
  name1: {
    title: 'Mr',
    options: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  },
  name2: {
    title: 'Mrs',
    options: ['C', 'D', 'E']
  }
};

function myFunction(optionSearch) {
  for (var key in myObject) {
    if (myObject[key].options.includes(optionSearch))
      console.log(key + ' has : ' + optionSearch)
  }
}

myFunction('C')
myFunction('A')
```

You could also [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys which have an `options` value which [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the given `option`

```js
let myObject = {name1:{title:'Mr',options:['A','B','C'],},name2:{title:'Mrs',options:['C','D','E'],}};

function getKeys(obj, option) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k].options.includes(option))
}

console.log(getKeys(myObject, 'C')) // [ "name1", "name2"]
console.log(getKeys(myObject, 'A')) // [ "name1" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Object.keys(myObject)
  .filter((key) => {
    return myObject[key].options.includes(optionSearch)
  })
```